# Unstable internet when Overwatch is running

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

When I run [Overwatch](https://overwatch.com) on a Windows 10 build 19613 laptop with a Intel®️ Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz on the latest drivers from Intel ([21.90.3.2](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29520/Windows-10-Wi-Fi-Drivers-for-Intel-Wireless-Adapters?product=99445)) I get loads of packet loss, as can be seen in this image
[image: packet loss while running & not running overwatch]

The issue is likely not CPU-utilization, as that sits at around 20%. Nor is it related to bandwidth usage. When I fully saturate my connection with https://fast.com, I still don't lose packets. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

I've tried turning down the roaming aggressiveness on the Intel WiFi adapter, and tweaking various other settings, but nothing helped.

Comment: You could be reaching the maximum amount of connections. Is this all on the same computer?

Comment: It's all on my Razer laptop, yes. I'll look into the max connections thing

Comment: Removing the limit did help - there's rarely packet loss now, but the latency still varies from 7ms to 80ms pretty randomly. Your comment was the fix, so it should really become the answer, although it didn't fix the problem 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that bandwidth is not the problem, it is likely that you are hitting a connection limit.